# Bug in my code causes line counting error. Please advise

Tags: java

There are 4 lines, but the program detects only 1 line.
What might be wrong with my code?

Contents of input file:

> To be, or not to be: that is the question.
>
> Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
>
> The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
>
> Or to take arms against a sea of troubles.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class wordcount{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("What is the name of the file? ");

  String file = console.nextLine();

  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(file));

  int wordCount = 0;
  while(input.hasNext()){
     String word = input.next();
     wordCount++;
  }

  int lineCount = 0;
  while(input.hasNextLine()){
     String line = input.nextLine();
     lineCount++;
  }   

  System.out.println("total words = " + wordCount);
  System.out.println("total lines = " + lineCount);

  }

}
```

Comment: Nice poem you wrote there.

Comment: Are you sure your program gets the right file?

Comment: Yeah, it gets the right file. The word count worked for me. But the line count is giving me 1 for some reason, instead of 4.

Comment: Your lines are already consumed by first while loop.

Comment: @ToddSewell: As far as I know, William is not a participant on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first `while` loop is consuming the entire file, and then there's nothing left but the final newline. Instead, make your top-level loop the line counter, and in each iteration split on whitespace, tokenize, or scan the line to find the number of words:

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    lineCount++;
    wordCount += line.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: "wordcount.java:19: error: illegal escape character" wordCount += input.split("\s+").length;

Comment: @Kizzo Should be `split("\\s+")` (two backslashes).

Comment: And beware: This code, as it currently stands, will count a blank line as one word. Can be fixed by wrapping the `wordCount` line with `if (! line.trim().isEmpty())`

Comment: Got another error message......wordcount.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
         wordCount += input.split("\\s+").length;
                           ^
  symbol:   method split(String)
  location: variable input of type Scanner

Comment: I just compiled and tested it as it is at this moment. Worked fine.  Nice approach.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I always trip up when I have to do regex in Java instead of Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line *between* your two `for-loops`:

```
input = new Scanner(new File(file));  /* get a new scanner to start over */
```

The scanner read from beginning to end, exhausting the input. I don't see a way to reset the scanner pointer to the beginning of the file (`Scanner.reset()` doesn't do it).

Comment: Don't forget to call `input.close()`

Comment: Won't the gc just take care of it? I guess for the first Scanner. 2nd one though...

Comment: You should *always* exercise good resource management. That way, later on when the programs get more complex, it's second nature and you won't forget.

Comment: I actually am pretty careful with that stuff when I'm writing code, very symmetrical, but since you mentioned it and it was just an example, I was focusing in the main part of the question.

Comment: Which was good, and why I up-voted the answer. But since you're reusing the variable, you should make sure to clean up the old value first.

Comment: I'm not sure I would bother calling close on a scanner I was throwing the reference away to like that.  But that's a matter of taste and style.  You could argue that there is a performance vs. storage tradeoff, neither of which amount to a hill of beans in *this* case. I always weigh it.

Comment: What you should argue, is that an open file maintains a lock on the file (on Windows at least), and uses a file handle, and file handles are limited. It may take *ages* before the finalizer runs and closes it for you. Sure, not in this example, but as I said, learn good behavior, and it becomes second nature.

Comment: OK so you're saying by not closing it, the file can't be deleted on some systems, so just do it to play it safe... I hadn't really thought of that, so thanks.